# Diffing only modified files in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial it's possible to `hg status` only the modified/added/removed files by doing:

```
hg st -m
hg st -a
hg st -r
```

Is it possible to obtain the same behaviour for the `diff` command? From the man page, it seems not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to use something like this:

```
hg status -mar --no-status | xargs hg diff
```

The `--no-status` flag insures that just the file name is sent to STDOUT.

Comment: That won't work if you (wrongly!) have spaces in your files names.  Then you need to use `--print0` and `-0` in hg and xargs, respectively.

Comment: If the `color` option is set, then both `hg` commands must also include `--color=never`.

Comment: Thank you. I've created aliases for these commands and I'm now happy. It's a pity `hg diff -m` is not available, though.

Comment: If you need to do this for a past revision, make sure you mention the revision on both sides eg. `hg st --rev 500:505 -m --no-status | xargs hg diff -r 500:505`